# Mathlib keeps rebuilding even after I `lake exe cache get`

Tags: lean, mathlib, lake

Despite the fact that I executed `lake exe cache get`, `lake build` keeps on building Mathlib, which takes hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `lake build` will keep building mathlib if your mathlib dependency uses a lean version different from yours.

So, to build everything using cache:

1. Copy your mathlib's Lean version into your project's lean-toolchain

   ```bash
   cp lake-packages/mathlib/lean-toolchain lean-toolchain
   ```
2. Clean cache to make sure everything goes fine

   ```bash
   rm -rf lake-packages
   rm -rf build
   lake exe cache clean!
   ```
3. Get cached built files

   ```bash
   lake exe cache get
   ```
4. Finally, build

   ```bash
   lake build
   ```

Comment: You can run `lake clean` instead of the `rm -rf`s